# Orientable vs Oriented connected sum

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I am confused about defining the connected sum of two $\color{red}{oriented}$ $n$-dimensional connected smooth manifolds without boundary, where $n\geq 2$. Could anyone help me to clear my confusion? I have written some guesses; maybe you can comment on these also. Thanks in advance.

---

So, let $M,M'$ be two connected $\color{blue}{orientable}$ $n$-dimensional connected smooth manifolds. Let $\varphi\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M$ and $\varphi'\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M'$ be two smooth embeddings of closed unit balls. Define $$\sharp(M,M'):=\frac{\big(M\backslash \varphi(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)\big)\sqcup \big(M'\backslash \varphi'(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)\big)}{\varphi(p)\sim \varphi'(p),\ p\in \Bbb S^{n-1}}.$$

---

> Question $(1)$ Is $\sharp(M,M')$ always $\color{blue}{orientable}$?

> Question $(2)$ Is it also true that if we $\color{red}{pick\
>  orientations}$ for $M,M'$, then $\color{red}{one\ can\ orient}$
> $\sharp(M,M')$ so that orientation of $\sharp(M,M')$ coincides with
> the orientation of $M\backslash \varphi(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$?

I guess the answers to both questions are positive.

---

I know the following: If we pick orientations for $M, M'$ and choose $\varphi$ as orientation-preserving and $\varphi'$ as orientation-reversing then $\sharp(M, M')$ has a unique orientation that  coincides with the orientations of $M\backslash \varphi(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$ as well as $M'\backslash \varphi'(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$. And the proof is based on the following theorem:

**Richard Palais Theorem:** Let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold without boundary. (If $X$ is orientable, pick an orientation for $X$) Let $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_m\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow X$ and $\psi_1,...,\psi_m\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow X$ be two sets of smooth embeddings with pairwise disjoint images (If $X$ is orientable, then we demand that all $\varphi_i,\psi_j$ are orientation-preserving or that all are orientation-reversing). Then there exists an isotopy $F\colon X\times [0,1]\to X$ with $F(-,0)=\text{id}_X$ such that the diffeomorphism $F(-,1)\colon X\to X$ sends $\varphi_i$ to $\psi_i$, i.e., $F\circ \varphi_i=\psi_i$ for all $i=1,...,m$.

---

*For the following two questions, pick orientations for $M, M'$ and choose both $\varphi,\varphi'$ as orientation-preserving smooth embedding.*

> Question $(3)$  Is it true that if $M$ has an orientation-reversing
> diffeomorphism, then $\sharp(M,M')$ is again
> $\color{blue}{orientable}$, and $\color{red}{there\ exists\ unique\ orientation}$ for
> $\sharp(M, M')$ that coincides with the orientations of $M\backslash
>  \varphi(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$ as well as $M'\backslash
>  \varphi'(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$?

My guess is that it is again true; probably one needs to pick an orientation for $\sharp(M, M')$ that coincides with the orientation of $M'\backslash \varphi'(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$. Now, composing an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism $M\to M$ with $F(-,1)\colon M\to M$ (see Richard Palais Theorem), one can produce a diffeomorphic copy of $\sharp(M, M')$ having the same orientation of $\sharp(M, M')$.

> Question $(4)$ Is it true that if neither of $M, M'$ has no
> orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, then though $\sharp(M, M)$ is
> $\color{blue}{orientable}$, it is impossible to $\color{blue}{pick\ an\
>  orientation}$ for $\sharp(M,M')$ that coincides with the orientations
> of $M\backslash \varphi(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$ as well as $M'\backslash
>  \varphi'(\text{int }\Bbb B^n)$?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Palais' disc theorem is not relevant to the question of orientability. It is relevant in arguing that the (oriented) connected sum is independent of the chosen discs up to (oriented) diffeomorphism.

Let the set-up be as in your question. You can find open collar neighborhoods of $\varphi(S^{n-1})$ in $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ and $\varphi^{\prime}(S^{n-1})$ in $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$, which glue together to give an open bicollar $U$ around the embedded copy of $S^{n-1}$ in $M\# M^{\prime}$. Now $M\#M^{\prime}$ is the union of the three open subsets $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$, $U$ and $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ , each intersecting only the ones written adjacent to it. Assume you're given an orientation of $M$, hence an orientation of $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$. The intersection $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)\cap U$ is connected (here, $n\ge2$ is used) and $U$ is connected (again, $n\ge2$) and orientable, so this determines a unique orientation of $U$ compatible with the orientation on $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$. In the same manner, but reverse, the intersection $U\cap M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ is connected and $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ is connected (using $n\ge2$ again) and orientable, so this determines a unique orientation of $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ compatible with the orientation on $U$. These compatible orientations on $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$, $U$ and $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ glue together to a unique orientation of $M\#M^{\prime}$, which is compatible with the orientation on $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ coming from the orientation on $M$. This answers questions (1) and (2) affirmatively.

To answer questions (3) and (4), we conduct a more explicit analysis of the above. Note that the uniqueness claim of the previous paragraph means we only have to understand what orientation the unique orientation of $M\#M^{\prime}$ induced by the orientation on $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ induces on $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$. Choose a collar $c\colon[0,1)\times S^{n-1}\rightarrow M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$, which coincides with the given embedding $\varphi\vert_{S^{n-1}}$ at the boundary. The fact that $\varphi\colon B^n\rightarrow M$ is orientation-preserving means that $\varphi\vert_{S^{n-1}}\colon S^{n-1}\rightarrow\partial(M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n))$ is orientation-reversing if the codomain is equipped with the boundary orientation (since $\varphi$ pushes forward inward-pointing tangent vectors along $S^{n-1}$ to outward-pointing tangent vectors along $\partial(M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n))$). This in turn implies that the collar $c$ is orientation-preserving (since the positively oriented tangent vector to $[0,1)$ at $0$ pushes forward to an inward-pointing tangent vector along $\partial(M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n))$).

Next, choose a collar $c^{\prime}\colon(-1,0]\times S^{n-1}\rightarrow M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$. The two collars glue together to the bicollar $C\colon(-1,1)\times S^{n-1}\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}U\subseteq M\#M^{\prime}$. If we now follow the construction from earlier explicitly, the orientation on $M$ determines the orientation of $U$ obtained by pushing forward the standard orientation of $(-1,1)\times S^{n-1}$ along $C$, by the previous paragraph. This in turm means the compatible orientation on $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ is uniquely determined by making $c^{\prime}$ orientation-preserving. Reversing the arguments from the previous paragraph, this is equivalent to $\varphi^{\prime}$ being orientation-reversing (note crucially the difference between one collar neighborhood defined on $[0,1)\times S^{n-1}$ and the other on $(-1,0]\times S^{n-1}$). From this, we obtain that two orientations on $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ induce an orientation on $M\#M^{\prime}$, agreeing with the given ones on $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ and $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ respectively, if *and only if* the embedded discs are oppositely oriented.

I want to stress that this is the *expected* behavior. To illustrate this, let's think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the union of upper half-space $\mathbb{H}_+^n$ and lower half-space $\mathbb{H}_-^n$, which is topologically the local model for gluing manifolds along their boundaries. The intersection $\mathbb{H}_+^n\cap\mathbb{H}_-^n=\partial\mathbb{H}_+^n=\partial\mathbb{H}_-^n$ is a hyperplane and reflection along this hyperplane is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{H}_+^n$ and $\mathbb{H}_-^n$, which is the identity on the boundary, but it reverses orientations! So if you want to glue upper and lower half-space along their boundary to get $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the *oriented* category, they need to be oppositely oriented. Equivalently, you glue them along an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism. This manifests in the above proof, which is basically noting that if you identify the boundaries in the given manner, what looks outward-pointing in one gluing component has to look inward-pointing in the other and vice versa.

**Edit:** Ok, so if you have embeddings $\varphi\colon B^n\rightarrow M$ and $\varphi^{\prime}\colon B^n\rightarrow M^{\prime}$, let $M\#_{(\varphi,\varphi^{\prime})}M^{\prime}$ denote the specific connected sum constructed from this data. Palais' theorem implies that if $\psi\colon B^n\rightarrow M$ and $\psi^{\prime}\colon B^n\rightarrow M^{\prime}$ are two more embeddings, such that $\varphi,\psi$ and $\varphi^{\prime},\psi^{\prime}$ are respectively equioriented, then $M\#_{(\varphi,\varphi^{\prime})}M^{\prime}\cong M\#_{(\psi,\psi^{\prime})}M^{\prime}$. Thus, we can write $M\#_{(\pm,\pm)}M^{\prime}$, where the signs denote if the respective embeddings preserves or reverses orientations, and obtain 4 well-defined diffeomorphism types. Now if $(\varphi,\psi)$ is a pair of embeddings, then $(\varphi r,\psi r)$, where $r\colon B^n\rightarrow B^n$ is a reflection (so orientation-reversing), is a pair of embeddings whose signs are opposite and you can see immediately that $M\#_{(\varphi,\psi)}M^{\prime}$ and $M\#_{(\varphi r,\psi r)}M^{\prime}$ are described by the same equivalence relation on the same space, hence equal. Thus, there really are only two diffeomorphism types worth considering, $M\#_+M^{\prime}$ and $M\#_-M^{\prime}$, where the sign now denotes whether these are realized by a pair of embeddings that have the same or the opposite effect on the respective orientation. Conventionally, one writes $M\#M^{\prime}$ to mean the diffeomorphism type $M\#_-M^{\prime}$, because this is the one that comes with a natural orientation compatible with both $M$ and $M^{\prime}$, as discussed previously.

*These two diffeomorphism types can be genuinely different.* The standard example is that $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2\#-\mathbb{CP}^2$ have different signatures, so they aren't even homeomorphic. *However*, if $M$ has an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism $\alpha\colon M\rightarrow M$ and $(\varphi,\psi)$ realizes $M\#_-M^{\prime}$, then $(\alpha\varphi,\psi)$ realizes $M\#_+M^{\prime}$ and you can check that the diffeomorphism $M\setminus\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)\rightarrow M\setminus\alpha\varphi(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ induced by $\alpha$ glues together with the identity on $M^{\prime}\setminus\varphi^{\prime}(\mathrm{int} B^n)$ to yield a diffeomorphism $M\#_-M^{\prime}\cong M\#_+M^{\prime}$. The same argument works with the factors interchanged, of course. In total, we obtain that if one of $M$ or $M^{\prime}$ possesses an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, there is only one diffeomorphism type of manifolds that can be obtained from connected sum constructions, but if neither of them has an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, you can get two distinct diffeomorphism types (I do not know if they always are).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. If I am right (though not sure), you are missing something in your answer. In questions 3 and 4, I asked whether the existence of orientation-reversing self diffeomorphism helps us orient the connected sum to match the orientations of summands even after choosing **both** $\varphi,\varphi'$ as orientation-preserving?

Comment: Both question (3) and (4) ask whether it is possible/impossible to orient $M\#M^{\prime}$ in a way consistent with both $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ under certain hypothesis. I argue that this is possible if and only if $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{\prime}$ are oppositely oriented in my answer, so if you choose both as orientation-preserving, it is never possible to orient $M\#M^{\prime}$ like that, completely irrespective of whether orientation-reversing self-diffeomorphisms exist or not.

Comment: I see it now. I mismatched with some other thing: Fixing orientations on $M,M'$, if we pick $\varphi,\psi\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M$ as orientation-preserving embeddings and $\varphi',\psi'\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M'$ as orientation-reversing embeddings, with two other embeddings $\alpha\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M(\text{orientation-reversing})$ and $\beta\colon \Bbb B^n\hookrightarrow M'(\text{orientation-preserving})$, then

Comment: $$M\sharp_{(\varphi,\varphi')}M'\cong M\sharp_{(\psi,\psi')}M'\cong M\sharp_{(\varphi,\beta)}M'\cong M\sharp_{(\alpha,\psi')}M',$$ i.e, they are *orientable manifolds and diffeomorphic*. Am I right now?

Comment: In other words, once $M, M'$ are oriented, no matter how we construct connected sum always ends up giving orientable manifolds of the same diffeomorphism type.

Comment: I'll make an edit to address this.

Comment: With regards to your last sentence, there exist two closed simply connected manifolds $M$ and $N$, neither of which admits an orientation reversing diffeomorphism, but for which $M\sharp N$ is diffeomorphic to $M\sharp - N$.  For starters, according to Remark 2.8 here, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06582.pdf, there is an exotic $1240$-dimensional sphere $\Sigma$ for which $\Sigma$ is $7$-torsion and $\mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp \Sigma$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}P^{310}$.  Taking $M = \mathbb{H}P^{310}$, $M$ admits not orientation reversing diffeo from Lefschetz.  (continued)

Comment: Taking $N = \Sigma$, $N$ admits no orientation reversing diffeo since the inverse of an exotic sphere is the same sphere with opposite orientation, so exotic spheres with orientation reversing diffeos all have order $2$.  On the other hand, we have $\mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp -\Sigma \cong (\mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp \Sigma)\sharp -\Sigma \cong \mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp (\Sigma \sharp -\Sigma)\cong \mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp S^{1240}\cong \mathbb{H}P^{310}$.  Thus $\mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp \Sigma \cong \mathbb{H}P^{310}\cong\mathbb{H}P^{310}\sharp -\Sigma.$

Comment: Thanks for the wild counterexample!

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks again for your explanation. So, according to your explanation $$\Bbb CP^2\sharp_-\Bbb CP^2=\Bbb CP^2\sharp \Bbb CP^2\not\cong\Bbb CP^2\sharp \overline{\Bbb CP^2}=\Bbb CP^2\sharp_+\Bbb CP^2,$$ where for two oriented manifolds $M,M'$  we write $$M\sharp M':=M\sharp_-M':= M\sharp_{(+,-)}M'\cong M\sharp_{(-,+)}M'$$ and $$M\sharp_+M':= M\sharp_{(+,+)}M'\cong M\sharp_{(-,-)}M'.$$

Comment: $M\sharp_+M'\cong M\sharp_-M'$ $\color{red}{if}$ either of $M,M'$ has orientation-reversing diffeomorphism (though $\color{red}{only\ if}$ direction may or may not hold). We always prefer $M\sharp_- M'$ as it has an orientation compatible with the orientations of both $M,M'$.

Comment: Thus, we have two cases $(1)$ $M\sharp_+M'\cong M\sharp_-M'$ and $(2)$ $M\sharp_+M'\not\cong M\sharp_-M'$. So, according to your explanation, we have the following: 

$\textbf{Case}(1):$ The orientation of $\overline{M\sharp_+M'}$ is compatible with the orientations of both $M$ and $M'$.

Comment: $\textbf{Case}(2):$  The orientation of $M\sharp M'$ compatible with the orientation of either $M$ or $M'$, but not of both of them. For example, let's assume the orientation of $M\sharp_+M'$ matches with the orientation of $M$ but not with the orientation of $M'$, then the orientation of $\overline{M\sharp_+M'}$ matches with the orientation of $M'$ but not with the orientation of $M$.

Comment: The orientation of $M\#M^{\prime}=M\#_-M^{\prime}$ is *always* compatible with both the orientations of $M$ and $M^{\prime}$ and either orientation of $M\#_+M^{\prime}$ is *never* compatible with both the orientations of $M$ and $M^{\prime}$. This is what I argue in the first part of my answer. It has nothing to do with when $M\#_-M^{\prime}$ and $M\#_+M^{\prime}$ are or aren't diffeomorphic.